# Evaluating the integral $ \int_0^1 \frac{e^{-y^2(1+v^2)}}{(1+v^2)^n}dv$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, gaussian-integral, gaussian

I am trying to evaluate the integral
$$
 \int_0^1 \frac{e^{-y^2(1+v^2)}}{(1+v^2)^n}dv = e^{-y^2}\int_0^1 \frac{e^{-y^2v^2}}{(1+v^2)^n}dv
$$
for $n\in \mathbb{N}$.For n=1 one finds [Owen's T function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Owen%27s_T_function), i.e.
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{e^{-y^2(1+v^2)}}{(1+v^2)}dv=2\pi \operatorname{T}\left(\sqrt{2} y,1\right) = \frac{\pi}{2} \operatorname{erfc}(y) \left(1 - \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{erfc}(y)\right)
\end{align}
A nice source on the Owen's T function is [[2](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/10652469.2015.1111889)]. In [[3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2556615/how-to-find-int-frace-x2x2-1-dx?noredirect=1)] they state that
\begin{align}
\int \frac{e^{-v^2}}{v^2 + 1} dv ,
\end{align}
has no anti-derivative. Hence, I do not suspect one can find one for our integral.

This integral occurs in a series I am integrating over for a approximation I am performing. Hence, it would already be nice if I could find the second (n=2) and third (n=3) term. Has someone an idea how to evaluate the integral. Many thank in advance!

Comment: You can obviously write it as a hypergeometric function, but I'm not sure whether it would be of any use to you in that form.

Comment: In further calculation I have to take convolutions of the results so it is not ideal. However, I do take what I can get! :p

Comment: That's essentially the $n-1$th antiderivative of the $T$ function which afaik has been uninvestigated.

Comment: The $n=2$ case requires evaluation of $\int_0^1\exp(-uv^4-(2u+y^2)v^2-(u+y^2))\,dv$ and because the upper limit isn't $\infty$ it is unlikely there is a closed form here either.

Answer (score 1):

I transformed your integral. Maybe this is helpful. Note that:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty }x^{n-1}e^{-(1+v^{2})x}dx=\frac{\Gamma(n) }{(1+v^{2})^{n}}$$$$\int_{0}^{1}e^{-v^{2}a}dv=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\operatorname{erf}\sqrt{a}}{2\sqrt{a}}.$$ Therefore the solution is, $$\int_{0}^{1 }\frac{e^{-y^{2}(1+v^{2})}}{(1+v^{2})^{n}}dv=\frac{1}{\Gamma(n) }\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\infty }e^{-(1+v^{2})y^{2}}x^{n-1}e^{-(1+v^{2})x}dvdx$$$$\frac{e^{-y^{2}}}{\Gamma(n) }\int_{0}^{\infty }x^{n-1}e^{-x}(\int_{0}^{1}e^{-v^{2}(x+y^{2})}dv)dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}e^{-y^{2}}}{2\Gamma(n) }\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{x^{n-1}e^{-x}\operatorname{erf}\sqrt{x+y^{2}}}{\sqrt{x+y^{2}}}dx.$$